# How to write custom indexes for typo3 solr search?

Tags: solr, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

How to write custom indexing for custom module's records in typo3 solr search. So that search records can be displayed individually.
I have referred https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/solr/Backend/IndexQueue.html#indexing-custom-records but this doesn't give me records list in search list.

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve or tried already. What is the TS you're using, hoe do you collect the result. And what is your desired result?

Comment: Hi pim, I want to show the records of my custom modules ie. products, news etc. But when i do write the TS configuration for solr search custom modules with reference to the link i had attached in my question. But i do not get the search results with records data, it only returns page's link only.

Comment: Are you sure records are available in the solr index? Does the solr dashboard give you proper results ?

Comment: Not what I meant. I meant your solr index. Do you have a way to check to contents of your index? Through a solr dashboard for instance?  And could you show me the TS you've build for this custom records. Also, do you have the scheduler running properly?

Comment: Hi Pim, My issue was solved for custom module indexing. Do you have idea can we use solr tika extension with solr 5.0.0 extension ?

Comment: Good to hear. Would you like to share your solution as an answer please. And for the tika question. I don't know, but [solr 5 documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_0_0/) mentions tika so I guess it's possible

Comment: I was doing right but missing to index all items that's why records were not in search.